# Lit 3 Standard Decorators not allowed on field

Tags: javascript, lit

The error thrown: `Uncaught Error: Unsupported decorator location: field`

Example class using the Lit [@queryDecorator](https://lit.dev/docs/api/decorators/#query) for a field to query from the components shadow-dom.

```
import {query} from 'lit/decorators.js';
import {html,LitElement} from 'lit';

class MyElement extends LitElement {
  @query('iframe,video') accessor player;
}
```

I have tried with/without the `accessor`. Setting the `player =null` for some sort of initialization.

Babel is used in the project with what should be the proper plugin with specified version for standard decorator support. Using Babel Preset-Env as well.

```
['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', {version: '2023-05'}]
```

Maybe I have missed something in the Lit 3 [documentation](https://lit.dev/docs/components/decorators/#decorators-babel) around this? Maybe something in the project build process isn't compatible while using rollup.

Comment: That should work with the `accessor` keyword. I can't say why it wouldn't without seeing a reproduction or other configurations. Here's a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vmwekn?file=index.js

Comment: I have put a pause on this for now. Thinking it is related to rollup configuration. If I find out what it is, I will post an update.